# Directed, local EMP?

Tags: technological-development

Hoons in the news again this morning.  Is a directional, contained electromagnetic pulse possible?  I had a mental image of a helicopter crew finding an "illegal race meet", firing a "freeze ray" type hand-held EMP generator, and frying all the electrics in the vehicles within, say, 30m on the ground.

Comment: What does Hoons mean?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon It's an Aussie term: [hoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoon)

Comment: wasn't there a scene in one of the more early Fast&Furious Movies where they did something like this? From a chopper? But... long time not seen, but I think it wasn't an area effect weapon, so not the kind of stuff you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently so. There is the [Bofors HPM Blackout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bofors_HPM_Blackout) built by BAE systems, which is described as being capable of destroying a wide range of consumer-grade electronic devices. It weighs "less than 500kg", I'm no expert on helicopter airframes/payloads but it seems like a viable helicopter mounted EM weapon. There are a range of other systems that have been developed, or which are in development, towards the aim of disabling electronic devices (mainly missiles) but this is the most portable one I could find - unless we include the so called "HERF guns" that hobbyists have been constructing and posting to youtube. I'm not sure I'd call any of these people an entirely credible source, however the idea going around the internet is that the magnetron from a microwave oven can be re-purposed to create a jury-rigged RF weapon, capable of inducing current and thereby destroying electronic devices, not to mention causing thermal damage. You might want to watch some of their videos to get some ideas about how your street racers might try and build something to shoot back at the helicopters.

This might not be quite the kind of 'pulse' you're thinking of. The other technique, which has been around for a while now, is the [explosively pumped flux compression generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator). Instead of using a high voltage source and/or capacitors to create a reusable device, these human-portable single-use devices use explosives to provide a pulse of "millions of amperes and tens of terawatts". These are likely more powerful than the more modern reusable weapons, and they're apparently significantly more portable.

Edit: I appear to have misunderstood — explosively pumped flux compression generators are more like bombs than generators. They'll definitely act as a deterrent to street racers, however, but so would regular bombs, once we've escalated this far....

Comment: While dropping a bomb with an EMP generator aboard is probably overkill for cars, it will certainly disable even hardened electrical equipment.

Comment: @Thucydides I don't think the explosively pumped flux compression generators are bombs, as such. I didn't go into detail because I don't understand them fully, but I think they use the explosive to compress a coil, thereby compressing the magnetic field generated by that coil; this creates a colossal electromagnetic charge that is used to power an emitter? They sound fascinating, read the article if you want a proper explanation, I'm a dilettante lol.

Comment: The usual employment of  explosively pumped flux compression generators is to put them in bombs or missiles since the explosion will destroy the generator anyway, and you want a long stand off between you and the device. You could mount it in other ways, but be prepared for an EMP pulse on top of you if you don't mount and trigger it remotely from your location.

Comment: @Thucydides ah ok, yes I'm not sure why I thought only the coil itself would explode, or why I thought the resulting pulse could be controlled or directed in any way! I should probably update the answer to note that these are bombs, not emitters.

Comment: The BAE systems device doesn't say anything about it being a directed weapon.

Comment: It's supposedly equipped with a [horn antenna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_antenna)

Comment: Some other implementations are mentioned in [this article](http://www.miltechmag.com/2014/03/todays-directed-energy-weapons-meeting.html?m=1)

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously possible to create a directional electromagnetic pulse, since you can create a directional radio beam. A pulse can be as little as a very high transmitted power for a very short time. The question I can't answer, is what power level of microwaves is needed to fry the engine-control unit (ECU) in a car. Incidentally, if you just want to *stop* a car rather than *permanently immobilize* it, the requirement is lessened to what power is needed to cause the microprocessor in the ECU to crash. (A mobile phone can crash a PC if the covers are off and the phone is within a couple of feet when a call or text comes in).

I vaguely recall having read a post by someone who had been driven to the edge of insanity by a person in his neighbouring appartment playing very loud music at all hours. He was an electronics engineer. His final solution involved a large high-voltage capacitor, a spark gap, a microwave resonant cavity,  a microwave horn pointed at the wall, and a high-voltage low-current source. I forget some details and won't spell out any others. Apparently the result was that the audio amp made a very loud bang and stopped working. A couple of nights later so did its replacement. The person next door decided the flat he was in was jinxed, and moved out.

This was a lesser requirement than killing a car because the audio amp was only a few feet (or possibly inches) away on the other side of a lightweight block wall, and presumably completely unhardened. An ECU is safety-critical equipment, cars are driven around airports and military bases, so one would expect a certain amount of attention is paid to hardening them against nearby radar transmitters at the health-and-safety maximum-permitted power levels. Also ECUs are well-sealed in metal enclosures to protect them from the elements (accidental? screening against radio).

I'd expect, but do not know, that one of those explosives-driven EMP generators could be made directional by putting it inside a metal horn pointed in the appropriate direction. The horn will be blown to bits very shortly after it directs the explosive-generated pulse, but it's only cheap sheet metal. However, that's a one-shot device that you would not want to employ anywhere near a helicopter.